# CSS3 Animations to only start after the page has been created

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have built a website that has lots of animations, using CSS3. The elements that are animated all have the `position` attribute set to `absolute`, and the container's `position` set to `relative`. Each element initially has a `top` and `left` value (set via the `style` attribute), but when the page loads, all the elements are initially animated to the position defined from `top:0px;left:0px`. Is there a way for the page to start off with the elements at there desired positions without them initially being animated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS animations are ready before your javascript. I usually add a class to the body so I know it's ready for animations...

```
   window.onload = function(){
      document.body.className += " animated";
   }
```

and then in your CSS

```
.box {
  /* usual styles here*/
}

.animated .box {
  -prefix-animation: animationName duration ease; 
}
```

Comment: Ooh, cunning fix, I like that